Confidence interval Standar Error of the Mean
I´m doing a repeatability study with 10 subjects that repeat 4 measures.
Calculate Standard Error of the Mean(SEm) = SD(4 measures)/Sq(4), for each subject.
Example:
234
226
239
244
Mean= 238
SEm = 2.016
After this, could be correct calculate confidence interval 95% for SEm like = SEm x 2.3534 ?
2.354 is statistic T.
Example:
IC95% SEm = 4.743
If this is correct, how I should report it?
I´m interesting in IC95 and SEm like a measure of repeatability, and I´m not really interesting in the mean of 4 values, but I don´t know if will be correct to report it without mean.
